# Groovy/Grails project run error

Tags: grails

I'm kind of new to grails, but when I try to run my project it fails and I get the following stacktrace:

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2013-06-26 14:01:37,372 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private")
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private")
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private")
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private")
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private")
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private")
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private")
->> 1549 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: Unable to initialize driver properties due to java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with modifiers "private"
->> 1073 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    987 | createSQLException in     ''
|    982 | createSQLException in     ''
|    927 | createSQLException in     ''
|   2772 | initializeProperties in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl
|   3312 | initializeDriverProperties in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    786 | <init> .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    381 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    305 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what the problem might be here? I recall it working before, and I tried this with a fresh STS-grails installation

### DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
}

hibernate {
        cache.use_second_level_cache = true
        cache.use_query_cache = false
        cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
        //    development {
        //        dataSource {
        //            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        //            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        //        }
        //    }

        development {
                dataSource {

                        pooled = true

                        dbCreate = "create" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
                        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
                        username = "root"
                        password = "root"

                        properties {
                                maxActive = 50
                                maxIdle = 25
                                minIdle = 5
                                initialSize = 5
                                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
                                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
                                maxWait = 10000
                         }

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the DataSource.groovy?

Comment: Yes. [link](http://pastebin.com/apzkd5by)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably an issue with the Spring-Loaded reload agent.

Try disabling it with the *noreloading* flag

```
YOUR_GRAILS_COMMAND_HERE -noreloading
```

Also check JIRA issues for potential bug fixes, etc.

Comment: wow adding the flag to the run configurations worked like a charm. Thank you so much, you definitely make this community proud.

Comment: Hi, Iam new to Grails development. I am facing the similar issue as here. Could you please suggest where I need to add this flag ?

Answer (score 4):

Having the same problem, not solved even using -noreloading, I found that it can be a problem related to the JDK version: it shows using  jdk1.7.0_25 while with JDK 1.6 or previous JDK 1.7 releases it does not happen, as seen  in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45029/mysql-exception-after-upgrading-from-java-6-to-java-7

Comment: You're right, the problem appeared when I had jdk1.7.0_25 installed. But this is how I have solved it.

Comment: Moving to JDK 1.7.0_45 and ensuring my IntelliJ project used this same SDK worked a charm - thanks!